# Jest coverage not covering index.js main file in coverage report

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have created a basic apollo graphql node.js project, so like node.js express projects it has index.js with basic server code i.e. server start at port etc and then other files having API call
I have used JEST framework to write test cases, but when running
"npm run test-coverage" it is showing results for all class but nothing for main index.js file
Below image shows it doesn't cover index.js file under source(src) folder
[image]

I tried using testmatcher to include all .js files , all files under src/ but not happening

Snapshot of jest.config.js file
[image]

Comment: Could you share the config you are using for jest (jest.config.js), especially the fields pertaining to coverage collection? (e.g. coveragePathIgnorePatterns, collectCoverageFrom etc.)

Comment: @KunalKukreja Edited post included jest.config.js

Comment: Please post your code in a code block, instead of using images :)

Comment: I think maybe we just need to add the [collectCoverageFrom](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array) ```collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**']```